# Экономия трафика

Tags: php

На странице используется самописная галерея, для которой сделано много HD фотографий. Как средствами php сгенерить превью небольшого размера и веса, и не сохраняя передать в браузер?

Answer (score 3):

то есть, Вы планируете каждый раз пережимать большие картинки? В таком случае траффика будет меньше, но нагрузка на процессор увеличиться в много раз. Почему нельзя нагенерировать маленьких картинок и просто положить в соседнюю папку?

по существу вопроса - попробуйте начать с [php gd](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.image.php). Там достаточно функций.

Answer (score 1):

кроме GD также имеется [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.resizeimage.php).  С более расширенным функционалом.

Comment: +exactimage, говорят, что он побыстрей, но найти хостера с этим модулем будет сложно. Хотя сейчас можно урвать впс по вполне вменяемой цене и ставить туда что угодно.

Comment: А ещё ImageMagick любит память. Сильно любит.